# Create excel macro to record contents of cell changing in real time

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell which sums data imported through RSS feeds, and I want to (eventually) create a macro to graph the changes in that cell over time. First, though, I'd like to create a (presumably) simple macro to record what value was in the cell every hour, for example, into a new sheet in list format. I can't seem to find anything of this nature in any corner of the internet. Perhaps I'm looking in the wrong places. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: what is your real problem?
Just write short question that can mean what you want. Didn't need long but still not clear of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, right-click the sheet tab, and click '**View Code**'

And paste in the below code:

```
'
public rngToTest as range

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Set rngToTest = Range("M24:P35")

        If Not Application.Intersect(rngToTest, Target) Is Nothing And Minute(Now) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "CHANGE EVENT:" & vbCrLf & Target.Address & vbCrLf & Target.Text
            call checkHourly
        End If
End Sub  


'
sub checkHourly
    ' here you store the data...
end sub
```

This event will fire when the cell is modified, and if the cell address is in your `rngToTest` variable then it checks the minute to only do it on the hour, then calls the code to save the values.

Comment: I suggest he then pastes the value in a new sheet called `data` with the date and time as the column a and the value in column b?